# Submitting TeX to ScholarOne

Tags: paper-submission, latex

I'm trying to submit a latex document to a SAGE journal using ScholarOne.

I'm having a hard time.

The (poor) documentation says that it accepts tex files, but the pdf it produces says that it cannot turn my tex into a pdf.

> Note: The following files were submitted by the author for peer
>   review, but cannot be converted to PDF. You must view these files (e.g. movies) online.
>
> response.tex

Is this just what it does with tex files? Should it compile them? I don't know. If it is not compiling, how do I get the error message?

Answer (score 8):

Both the Royal Society of Chemistry journals and the American Chemical Society journals use ScholarOne Manuscripts™ as their web submission platform. In both cases, **the system is able to compile LaTeX documents into a PDF file**. There are, however, strict requirements about the type of LaTeX document you can use. These are spelt out in a specific help section entitled *“Preparing and Submitting Manuscripts Using TeX/LaTeX”*.

> ACS Authors have two distinct options for submitting work authored in TeX:
>
> FAST Submission: Submit your own PDF file—and provide the native TeX and figures in a .zip file—and your own PDF file will be used for the review process.
>
> STANDARD Submission: Submit a complete and properly styled TeX file, figures, and references using the achemso style package. The TeX files will be converted to PDF by ACS Paragon Plus and used for the review process.

The help further states:

> When you upload your TeX/LaTeX Manuscript File, the system will analyze the file, and identify additional resource files referenced within the file (such as image files and bibliographic files) that are necessary to complete the document.

and

> Manuscript files prepared in TeX/LaTeX (Version 2.02 and earlier) will be used in journal production provided you adhere to the following guidelines:
>
> - Use only LaTeX2e. Use of plain TeX and RevTeX is discouraged.
> - Use generic style files whenever possible. Minimal formatting is all that is required in the document.
> - Include all sections of the article in a single file. Include the list of references within the LaTeX file. Captions must be created in the TeX/LaTeX document.
> - References should be cited in text using `\cite{}`, and the list of references should be itemized using `\bibitem{}`.
> - Use `\frac` to build fractions. Do not use `\over` or `\stackrel` to build fractions in displayed equations.
> - Use `\sum_{}^{}` for summations and `\prod_{}^{}` for products.
> - Use the array environment only to build true matrices, not for aligning multiline equations.
> - Use characters/symbols in the generic LaTeX character set only. Symbols from other sets may not translate correctly.
> - Avoid extensive use of `\newcommand` and `\def .
> - Some style files (text and bibliographic) that are available in the public domain may be used for most ACS journals, e.g., jacs.sty and jacs.bst; jpc.sty and jpc.bst; achemso. The use of the achemso style package is strongly encouraged. Please note that the ACS does not provide support for using these files.

A further requirement, which is not actually listed, is that all figures should be in the same directory (you cannot upload a directory structure). And, as noted, if you use bibtex, you have to run it manually and include the content of the `.bbl` file into your `.tex` file before upload.

---

So, in conclusion: **ScholarOne Manuscripts™ has the capability to support LaTeX compilation**. Whether this is enable or not for your specific journal/publisher, I cannot know. In any case, check the documentation! (or ask the editorial office)

Comment: I did all of this and still cannot make the site compile my paper. It is a useless piece of junk, and the tech support is so bad that apparently no one there knows what Latex is.

Answer (score 5):

For me, ScholarOne (Wiley submission) did not accept PDF upload and did not convert the latex sources. My solution was to convert the PDF to PS using pdf2ps (GhostScript). This was then properly converted back to PDF by ScholarOne. I absolutely do not understand why they are using such a stupid and confusion submission system, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

[This might be more ontopic at tex.stackexchange.com.]

What you received sounds like an error, but is vague. First, of course talk to technical support if you can get hold of any. These systems are often set up to only accept a minimal set of LaTeX packages. If you are using any non-standard packages, see if you can remove them or include the functionality in the document itself. And of course talk to technical support if you can get hold of any.

See also [Submitting a journal article as a single tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/submitting-a-journal-article-as-a-single-tex-file).

EDIT: Peter says the system is not trying to convert at all, and he should know. However, I'll leave this answer here for now. If anyone thinks it should be removed, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this out after about 3 hours. Thing is, even though the system tells you there was an error, it actually HAS uploaded your files. You can see this if you click "Update file order", and here you can download the LaTeX log to see what went wrong. In my case it was because the system didn't have all the figures yet, because it only lets you upload 3 files at a time. Once I'd uploaded all the figures, and deleted all the extra files I'd uploaded in frustration, I was able to force it to compile by clicking "View PDF". Finally submitted. I hope this helps someone, somewhere.

Worst. Manuscript. Submission. System. EVER.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the Scholar One Manuscripts (S1M) system can convert Word files into pdf, it does not contain a LaTeX engine but will accept PDF files. In the journal I work (which uses S1M), we accept LaTeX manuscripts but explcitly ask authors to produce a pdf of the document for reviewing purposes. It is a mistake or omission by the journal to not explain that the file for review must be either Word or PDF. The LaTeX files can be uploaded but must be marked as "Not for review" which means they are not included in the file sent to the reviewer. You need to check with the journal how they prefer to handle it. In my case, I do not need the LaTeX files until the final revised manuscript so uploading them is of minor use; this, however, might vary between journals.

I do not know of any commnercial manuscript system in use that produces PDF from submitted LaTeX files but then I do not know all journals. In any case, the proper way with S1M should be to submit your files in LateXed PDF format (e.g. PDFLaTeX).

Comment: Actually, systems that create PDFs from LaTeX are not uncommon. I've come across more than one. I think initially the journal will accept a PDF, but eventually it will need the LaTeX file(s) to work with. Though I suppose it does not need to be necessarily uploaded through some automated system in that case.

Comment: IEEE does pdf compiling. But thanks for the insight about S1M.

Comment: It is possible but not journals I have seen at Wiley, Elsevier, Springer, Sage, Copernicus, AGU, IGS.

Comment: TeX support is common in math and physics journals.

Comment: I'm going through some pains right now trying to submit a latex file to [this journal](http://www.springer.com/social+sciences/criminology/journal/10940) which is published by Springer. So at least the manager by Springer allows you to compile latex files (problem currently is bibliography).

Comment: I think I once submitted to one of the ACM journals that had a system that converted PDFs to LaTeX. TOMACS, if I recall correctly.

Comment: -1; inaccurately contests the premise of the question. Some major journals that use ScholarOne (e.g. Bioinformatics) in fact *require* you to upload source .tex rather than output .pdf files.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem while trying to submit a manuscript to Publications of Astronomical Society of Australia (PASA) via ScholarOne. When I uploaded the latex source from Overleaf, the submission system complained "Unable to find any suitable files to generate the proof". It is sad that this old problem still exists.

The problem seems to be with ScholarOne's latex compiler. I have found it to be more restrictive than other similar systems and tools like overleaf. The problems are the following:

1. ScholarOne does not work well with .bib files. Their tech support told me to add the citations directly to the main .tex file rather than putting them in a .bib file. This amounts to replacing the `\bibliography{}` command with the contents of the .bbl file generated by BibTeX. This is quite surprising since the PASA template in overleaf uses a .bib file for bibliography.
2. ScholarOne does not work well with `\include{}` statements. I had to create one big .tex file by manually copy-pasting the contents of the .tex files which are `\include`-d in the main .tex file.
3. ScholarOne does not use pdflatex. This means that if you add PDF or PNG images in your manuscript, the compiler won't be able to determine its size. The safe option is to use images in the EPS format. I also had to flatten the EPS files (using Photoshop/GIMP) since their latex compiler can't deal with layers. I also added `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to the preamble.
4. File names can't have spaces in them. (Which is in general good latex advice.)
5. Some packages may not be supported or may not work as expected. In my case, the tcolorbox package did not work.

TL/DR: ScholarOne needs a lot of handholding to compile any decently complex latex document.